# ajax and jquery, can send data to sever but not receive it

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I'm extremely new to ajax/node/jquery so please excuse any rookie errors.

I'm trying to send data to a node server and update the page with the response using jquery, I can send the data to the server but am unable to get a response.
i am sure the success method is not firing as I never receive an alert.

So, my aim is on clicking the `size_button`, the contents of the `size_form` is sent to the server. The finished item will process the contents of `size_form` but for this example just sending back to the server and updating `response` is required.

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#size_button').click(function(e){
$('#response').html("searching for size...");
 var url = "http://localhost:8081/search_size"; // the script where you handle the form input.
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       crossDomain: true,
       url: url,
       data: $("#size_form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
       //data: $('#size_form');
       success: function(data)
       {
           alert(data); // show response from the php script.
       $('#response').html(data);
       }
     });
e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

});
});
```

Node.js Code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

app.post('/search_size', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
  response = {batch_size: req.body.batch_size};
if(req.body.batch_size){
    var size = req.body.batch_size;
    console.log('looking for batches with ' +size+ ' items');
    res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
  } else {
  console.log('recieved request for 0 items');
  }

  //res.end('request recieved...');
  res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
});

 var server = app.listen(8081, "localhost", function () {
 var host = server.address().address
 var port = server.address().port
 console.log("Server listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

})
```

HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>    
    <form action='' method='POST' id='size_form'>
    <p>search for size</p>
    <input type='text' name="batch_size" id='batchsize'/>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'id='size_button' method='POST'/>
    </form>
    <div id='response'></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you debug, where/how does it fail?  In your browser's debugging tools, is there an error on the console?  Does the JavaScript code execute as expected?  Is the AJAX call made?  Does it contain the data you expect?  What is the server's response?

Comment: @David apart from a `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing` issue, everything looks great which is whats confusing me. i recieve `looking for batches with 55 items
` in the server and `searching for size...` in the page, so i know the jquery button click is working. as i said before im pretty sure `success` isnt firing as i never get `alert(data);`

Comment: Sounds like the browser is blocking the request due to the Same Origin Policy (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).  Googling that error message returns many helpful results, including a variety of Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: "Except for the thing that's making it fail it works"?

Comment: @David i thought `crossDomain: true,` would of fixed that, i had a quick look but i keep finding reference to PHP. would the same fix apply to both node and PHP?

Comment: I think I might be going round in circles, I tried adding `dataType:"json",` to the ajax call and changing `data` from the buttons value to a json of `{'name' : 'test'}` but I still get nothing. Can anyone put me out my misery and provide a more detailed answer? After googling "access control allow origin missing" for a while I am still none the wiser as half the answers point to PHP servers and the majority of the rest not using ajax. I would like to stick to node and ajax if preferable unless anyone can suggest why PHP would be a better option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it turns out the trick is CORS or Cross Origin Resource Sharing, i managed to fix my problem by installing and using the cors module.

`npm install cors --save`

Server.js code:

import the module:

`var cors = require('cors')`

use the module with the server app variable:

`app.use(cors())`

for more info:
[www.npmjs.com/package/cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

Answer (score 0):

You were using the wrong response function. You want response.send() or response.json(). See http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.end